# Why am I getting +1 points?

Tags: support, reputation, downvoting

I've had a few times now where I get +1 for my points.  But when I look at my rep history, nothing shows up.  What I did notice however is that some of my downvotes seem to have disappeared.  I have reviewed a few first and late posts, and I did downvote some of those.  So if the question that I downvoted gets removed, am I being "refunded" my lost point for downvoting?

I've now seen posts where people are saying that this is what happens, but I still haven't found anything official from any docs or help pages.  I think this simple feature that could state why you got the one point would be easy enough to add in.  This way you don't have to go through your entire rep history with the "Show deleted posts" option ticked to find a removed post.  Just a simple "+1 refund for deleted post" would suffice.

Comment: When the bad answers you downvoted are removed you get your rep back, so +1 for every one the got deleted.

Comment: To address the edit, you must have one of those gray tags on a meta question. See them here http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags, this should be tagged `support` as it is not a bug but intended behavior that needs clarification.

Comment: @MarkKirby Thanks for clearing it all up!  I tried searching for the reason for the +1, including deleted questions and it's not clear anywhere.  Perhaps I'm not using the right search terms.  If you can post an answer with a link to where this is stated I'll accept it as an answer.  I still think however that when this happens, it should tell you WHY you got the +1, but it doesn't.

Comment: The reason is, your total rep is only based on the content that is actually on the site when the rep was calculated. So if you remove a downvoted question of yours you gain rep, remove an upvoted answer, you loose rep, same for votes on other peoples stuff. I was sure this was a duplicate but I can't find it anywhere, wait for someone with a bit more knowledge to give you a better answer than I could, with some documentation included.

Comment: Oh I understand the reversal concept, I just can't find it written anywhere stating that the system works like that.  I also noticed when looking at your own reputation, that there's a checkbox at the bottom to show removed posts.  My question is pointing out that this system isn't clear.

Comment: Here is a meta post on it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work That is the best place to look for this kind of information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ...temporary loss of 1 rep point *will be given back to you* in case the *answer is deleted*.

[Regain of reputation from downvoted and deleted answers - update FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197507/321647)